# Changing TMP text

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm making a ui which has 4 spell slots. I made it so that when my player collides with a tome gameobject, it gets added to my player's unequippedSpells array which is in my SpellSystem script.

```
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        Debug.Log("Finding Player");
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player")) {
            Debug.Log("Player Found");
            Spell fireball = gameObject.AddComponent<Spell>();
            fireball.spellData = fireballData;
            fireball.spellType = fireballType;
            spellSystem.AddSpell(fireball);
            spriteRenderer.enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

```
    public void AddSpell(Spell spell) {
        Array.Resize(ref unequippedSpells, unequippedSpells.Length + 1);
        spellEquipped = false;
    }
```

So then I want to make an inventory ui thing that displays the spells equipped. I want to make it so that if the player has an empty spell slot, the spell will go from unequipped to equipped and the spell ui will display all the equipped spells so I made an equippedspell() function which was

```
    public void EquipSpell(Spell spell, GameObject spellSlots) {
        int index = Array.IndexOf(equippedSpells, spell);
        if (index != -1) {
            Array.Resize(ref equippedSpells, equippedSpells.Length + 1);
            equippedSpells[equippedSpells.Length + 1] = spell;
            Array.Resize(ref unequippedSpells, unequippedSpells.Length - 1);
            GameObject labelObject = spellSlots.transform.GetChild(1).gameObject;
            TextMeshProUGUI label = labelObject.GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>();
            Debug.Log(label.text);
            label.text = spell.name;
            spellSlots.GetComponent<SlotStat>().hasSpell = true;
        }
    }
```

and the update() function for the SpellSystem script is

```
    private void Update() {
        if (equippedSpells.Length < spellSlots.Length && !spellEquipped) {
            if (spellSlots[equippedSpells.Length].GetComponent<SlotStat>().hasSpell == false) {
                EquipSpell(unequippedSpells[unequippedSpells.Length - 1], spellSlots[equippedSpells.Length]);
                spellEquipped = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

but when I run my game I get the error

> IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
> SpellSystem.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/Spells/SpellSystem.cs:24)

I'll put the full codes for the spellsystem and an example spell below

```
using System.Data;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class Spell : MonoBehaviour {
    public SpellDataSO spellData;
    public SpellTypeSO spellType;
}

public class SpellSystem : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Spell[] equippedSpells;
    public Spell[] unequippedSpells;
    public GameObject[] spellSlots;

    private bool spellEquipped;

    private void Update() {
        if (equippedSpells.Length < spellSlots.Length && !spellEquipped) {
            if (spellSlots[equippedSpells.Length].GetComponent<SlotStat>().hasSpell == false) {
                EquipSpell(unequippedSpells[unequippedSpells.Length - 1], spellSlots[equippedSpells.Length]);
                spellEquipped = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public void EquipSpell(Spell spell, GameObject spellSlots) {
        int index = Array.IndexOf(equippedSpells, spell);
        if (index != -1) {
            Array.Resize(ref equippedSpells, equippedSpells.Length + 1);
            equippedSpells[equippedSpells.Length + 1] = spell;
            Array.Resize(ref unequippedSpells, unequippedSpells.Length - 1);
            GameObject labelObject = spellSlots.transform.GetChild(1).gameObject;
            TextMeshProUGUI label = labelObject.GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>();
            Debug.Log(label.text);
            label.text = spell.name;
            spellSlots.GetComponent<SlotStat>().hasSpell = true;
        }
    }

    public void UnequipSpell(Spell spell) {
        int index = Array.IndexOf(unequippedSpells, spell);
        if (index != -1) {
            Array.Resize(ref unequippedSpells, unequippedSpells.Length + 1);
            unequippedSpells[unequippedSpells.Length + 1] = spell;
            Array.Resize(ref equippedSpells, equippedSpells.Length - 1);
        }
    }

    public void AddSpell(Spell spell) {
        Array.Resize(ref unequippedSpells, unequippedSpells.Length + 1);
        spellEquipped = false;
    }

    public Spell[] GetEquppedSpells() {
        return equippedSpells;
    }

    public Spell[] GetUnequippedSpells() {
        return unequippedSpells;
    }
}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Fireball : MonoBehaviour
{
    public SpellSystem spellSystem;
    public SpellDataSO fireballData;
    public SpellTypeSO fireballType;
    public SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;
    
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        Debug.Log("Finding Player");
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player")) {
            Debug.Log("Player Found");
            Spell fireball = gameObject.AddComponent<Spell>();
            fireball.spellData = fireballData;
            fireball.spellType = fireballType;
            spellSystem.AddSpell(fireball);
            spriteRenderer.enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I know that the problem is in the Update() function since the error is referring to line 24 which is in

```
    private void Update() {
        if (equippedSpells.Length < spellSlots.Length && !spellEquipped) {
            if (spellSlots[equippedSpells.Length].GetComponent<SlotStat>().hasSpell == false) {
                EquipSpell(unequippedSpells[unequippedSpells.Length - 1], spellSlots[equippedSpells.Length]);
                spellEquipped = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

specifically referring to

```
EquipSpell(unequippedSpells[unequippedSpells.Length - 1], spellSlots[equippedSpells.Length]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```cs
EquipSpell(unequippedSpells[unequippedSpells.Length - 1], spellSlots[equippedSpells.Length]);
```

In this line, you have two arrays that could trigger this exception.

1. `spellSlots[equippedSpells.Length]`
2. `unequippedSpells[unequippedSpells.Length - 1]`

We know that **1.** isn't the problem because it's called in the second `if` just before that line. Therefore, **2.** is the issue.

Most likely, `unequippedSpells` is **Empty** (*Length == 0*), which would mean you're trying to access `unequippedSpells[-1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an array for unequippedSpells and equippedSpells and resizing them, you should use an List. This would be cleaner. For your problem, use `unequipedSpells.Last()` from Linq. This will return the last element of the list and that will correct your problem.